# why does this ajax php parse function fail

Tags: php, ajax, parsing

Hi all I have made a gallery delete function which when i get working i will adapt for a pic reporting function (after) but when passing ajax the fuunction dosnt do anything here is some code snippets...

the link im using to fire off the function

```
$gallery_list .= '

<div class="pic_holder" onclick="DeletePhoto(\''.$filename.'\')">
<img class="pics" src="user/'.$u.'/'.$filename.'"></a></div>

';
```

the function

```
function DeletePhoto(filename) {
    var conf = confirm("Press OK to delete this photo.");
    if (conf != true) {
        return false;
    }
    _("deletelink").style.visibility = "hidden";
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/photo_system.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if (ajax.responseText == "deleted_ok") {
                alert("This picture has been deleted successfully. We will now refresh the page for you.");
                window.location = "photos.php?u=<?php echo $u; ?>";
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("delete=photo&filename=" + filename);
}
```

and for the ajax parser code

```
   if (isset($_POST["delete"]) && $_POST["filename"] != "") {
       $filename1 = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["filename"]);
       $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT user, filename FROM photos WHERE filename='$filename1' LIMIT 1");
       $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
       $user = $row[0];
       $filename = $row[1];
       if ($user == $log_username) {
           $picurl = "../user/$log_username/$filename";
           if (file_exists($picurl)) {
               if ($filename != "avatardefault.jpg") {
                   unlink($picurl);
               }
               $sql = "DELETE FROM photos WHERE filename='$filename1' LIMIT 1";
               $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
           }
       }
       mysqli_close($db_conx);
       echo "deleted_ok";
       exit();
   }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong at all? because when I click the button and I get confirmation box as I should but when I click OK, nothing happens, ps I really dont wish to edit the link that fires off the function as that part works, I feel the error is in one of the last two code snippets.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your post to properly indent your code. As it is it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: yer i dont know how plus i feel that shouldnt prevent code from working if it does then code should be made in such a way that it shouldnt effect how it runs, i find it easy on the eye when it is not indented and it looks like its been copyed when code is indented also it takes up more space when indented! because of all the spaces used, this is just my opinion though and i know not everyone will agree.

Comment: Use the space bar to indent. It may be easy for you to read without any whitespace, but it's hard for everyone else, which is going to make it a lot harder for you to get any help.

Comment: what i meant was i dont know what lines to indent or by how much as it makes no sense why code should be ever indented it dosnt effect how the code is processed, if that makes sense.

Comment: @uk_user2014 The main reason to indent code is usually to structure it for human reading. After programming for a while you will realize that it _really_ helps you when you have to debug nested nested ifs and loops. _Especially_ when when you are asking here indenting is important. You are asking a human to read your code. Unless you are a superhuman, you can't read as a computer. If you are worried about slowing down performance, you can [minify](http://minifyjavascript.com/) it before compiling. (minifying is making it as small as possible, so a machine can read it).

Comment: I have indented your code now by editing your post. All you have to do is accept the edit :)

Comment: @uk_user2014 It makes sense but it's a mistake. To quote Martin Fowler, "Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand." Humans (you and anyone you work with or anyone who inherits code you wrote) are the ones who have to read your code, change and extend it, find bugs in it, and so on. If it's hard to read it's a lot harder and a lot more expensive to maintain.

You may be able to read that code today, but if you set it aside for six months and come back to add a feature or fix a bug I guarantee it'll give you a headache.

Comment: is the code correct or have i made any mistakes?

Comment: Now the code is indented no-one seems to want to tell me if I have made any mistakes regarding this code, the code is more important than weather or not it is indented everyone!

Comment: HELLO HELP WITH CODE PLEASE SOMEONE!